# Windows Phone restore in-app purchase when a device is changed

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, in-app-purchase

Lets say I made some in-app purchases on a windows phone. Now I change my device and use the same Microsoft account. Will I still get the list of in-app purchases made from my old device when i call the below code?

`var allProductLicenses = CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses;`

Answer (score 1):

When you login to windowsphone.com you can see your current registered phone listed in the top right corner  bellow the search box. There under the dropdown list you have a option called purchase history. Click it and in the page that is given you see the apps you have already purchased. In that you can click reinstall and then the app will be sent to the phone you are currently using. If your device is new, you have to register it and then from the menu (at the bottom of the menu you can see other phones) select the phone you are using (in this case your new device) and then go to purchase history and the click on reinstall. Then your app should be sent to the new device. Before clicking on re-install you need to connect to Wi-fi and then go to settings and enable send apps to my phone using push notifications.

Comment: thanks Kasun, I want to know about in-app purchases, sorry for not mentioning this prior, I have modified my question

Answer (score 0):

Finally I had a word with Microsoft and they said, if the phone's MDN remains unchanged then all the purchases (Consumables and Durables) will be transferred